# wamp server not working on 8.1

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I just upgrade to win8.1 from win8 and I can't start wamp server (2.2 x64)

[image]

It was working fine on win8

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I just can't start wamp. Nothing happens when I click start, stop and restart all services.
127.0.0.1 / localhost is not oppening, cause wamp is stopped

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try checking that the Apache and MySQL services are still registered as services.

Look in Windows Services for services called - 'wampapache' and wampmysql'

Or if you have WAMPServer 64bit `wampapache64` and `wampmysqld64`

If they dont exist do the following:-

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Install Service
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
```

Then try to restart all services.

Comment: I had the exact same issue as the OP - tried this, and now Wamp turns Orange - an improvement, but still not green.

Comment: Aha!  Just have to also do the above steps for MySQL.

Comment: I had the same problem: I upgraded to Windows 8.1 and WAMP was stuck with a red "W". This fixed the problem. Thank you, thank you!

Comment: it turns green but it still has a lot of warnings and issues.

Comment: @George What warning and issues, ask another question itemising these warnings and issues.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So apparently, the solution to all the problems is to Install Microsoft Essentials for Windows 8. This will install the .NET framework with all the necessary parts in order to provide all the functionality Wamp has to offer :)

Comment: I had the port 80 in use issue and had found out that 'skype' utilizes port 80. try exiting skype if you have the issue of apache in wamp not starting.

Comment: @RiggsFolly When I followed your suggestion (*wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service*), I've a new cmd window open with: **Your port 80 is available, Install will proceed.    Press Enter to continue...**. Yet when I press *Enter* btn, the window is closed and nothing happens. If I do not do anything, nothing happens either... What's wrong?   *wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Install Service* doesn't yield anything either.

Answer (score 5):

After Upgrading of window to window 8.1.

Please click on the wamp icon go to apache then services and then click on install services. And then go to mysql and services and click on install services and the restart your wamp. And enjoy your coding. Hurry

Answer (score 1):

I've also gone through this situation. I checked the services and there "wampapche" and "wampmysqld" services are disable I've tried to start the services and the service didn't start stating a 1058 error. Then I changed the startup type from manual to automatic and now it's working.

Comment: You should chnabe the services to a Startup Type of `Manual`. Then you start the services using the Wampmanager icon `Start All Services`. Otherwise the services run all the time even when you are not developing/testing your site, which is a waste of resource.

Answer (score 1):

all of your's answers are wrong, not only wampserver but also xampp is not working on windows 8.1 because apache server is not running in windows 8.1 with port 80, becouse port 80 is system reserved port.

Comment: No it is not system reserved! It is however used by IIS which is installed by default now for some reason. If you are not using IIS uninstall it as it is just another attack vector that most people probably dont know exists and have no idea how to manage and/or secure!

Answer (score 0):

@Ahmed that has been what described on the above posts. The simple answer is after upgrade we need to restart the services as they are stopped and yes it depends on the user whether they are going to keep it running or closed as they can choose whether to start manually or automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Windows 8/8.1 are missing some essentials. The solution is to install Microsoft Essentials for Windows 8/8.1. This adds the .NET framework with all the necessary APIs that allow Wamp to function as designed. You can download Windows Essentials from herE: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/essentials . I have already tested this out on several devices, including my laptop and desktop running both Windows 8 and 8.1. Good luck! :)