# wamp server application error the directory name is invalid

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

i have reinstalled my win 8 ,then wampserver in old win 8 is still available, i try to access it but error message appears:

> Could not execute run action : the directory name is invalid

my question:

is possible to use wampsaerver that have installed in old win 8? because i need data of mysql and my web project

Comment: Because you have re-installed your OS ( Windows 8 ) the Apache(wampapache) and MySQL(wampmysql) services will no longer be registered as services, so look at this post to see what to do to re-register them. Its easily done from the wampmanager menu system. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445238/wamp-server-not-working-on-8-1/19450946#19450946

Answer (score 0):

rather than trying to run old wamp, reinstall new one. just copy all the files from

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\
```

and

```
C:\wamp\www
```

there and paste it somewhere before you perform reinstalling. and after you successfully install new copy of wamp, paste the file in same folders.
maybe that will help you save the data.